# How to play a DVD from a different region on the PS3?

Tags: dvd, media-center, ps3, regional-settings

I'm trying to play a region 4 DVD on a region 1 PS3 and, predictably, it refuses to play it with a message like "The DVD is from a different region". Is there any way to change that and play DVDs from any region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to Make a PS3 DVD Region Free](http://www.ehow.com/how_5032068_make-ps3-dvd-region.html) :

> Use the DVD-copier software to make a
>   copy of your DVD. Both Nero and
>   DVDXCopy Platinum will make direct
>   copies of commercial DVDs, so they'll
>   both work well for these purposes.
>   Making a copy will remove any region
>   coding the disc has and effectively
>   make it "Region 0," or "all-region."
>   As long as you own the DVD you are
>   copying, you are doing nothing
>   illegal.

Comment: The MPAA would disagree with that poster, and they would have a fair chance of winning if they took you to court.  The question of copying DVD's, even if you own them, is one of great debate and the MPAA and others have successfully sued people who have made copies of DVDs they own and failed at suing others.

Comment: @BBlake: The MPAA is one of the reasons I'm thankful for not living in the US.

Comment: agreed. The MPAA has no bearing on non-US people.

Comment: Not much of one yet.  But that isn't stopping them from trying.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not without modding or jailbreaking the PS3, or ripping the DVD and rewriting it region-free.

For all sorts of legal and license agreement reasons, the second option is probably less likely to land you in trouble.